# spring cloud config client does not load config files. Think the problem may be profile settins

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I have looked at past stack traces and I have all the correct settings. I think this is more a problem of the profile.

I am not using git as a data source but instead using S3 but it works, On my local when I run

http://localhost:8086/application/default

it returns

```
{
    "name": "application",
    "profiles": [
        "default"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": null,
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "s3:application",
            "source": {
                "environment.profile": "local",
```

on my pom I have set for spring boot

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
```

Spring cloud is

```
 <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```

Spring cloud is set

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Set starter config

```
<!-- config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

in the application yml for the client I have set

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: @activatedProperties@
  application:
    name: @artifactId@
  config:
    import: "configserver:"
  cloud:
    config: 
      enabled: true
      uri: http://localhost:8086
```

@activatedProperties@ is either local, dev,  qa, or prod.
Is the problem the fact that profile in this case is local and the config server is expecting default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed the problem.  Looking at my settings

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: @activatedProperties@
  application:
    name: @artifactId@
  config:
    import: "configserver:"
  cloud:
    config: 
      enabled: true
      uri: http://localhost:8086
```

Config server will process it as follows

```
http://localhost:8086/my-client/local
```

my-client being the name of the application local being the profile. It needs to map to a yml file with all the config data on'

The yml file for this will be called my-client-local.yml. I will also have have
my-client-qa.yml, my-client-dev.yml, my-client-prod.yml so it picks up the right profile